# Cannot send error message with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot send an error message for a removerole command if an invalid role name was given. Say for example, it would send an error message if the role was not found in the server. It would send the error message saying the role was not found. I tried

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def removerole(self, ctx, member:discord.Member, *, role:discord.Role):
      if role not in ctx.guild.roles:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, I could not find that role, please try again!')
        return
```

But this would not send an error message if I gave an invalid role. Though, it would work if I gave a valid role name. What do I need to change in order to get this error message to work? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading (this post is a bit rude, but it gets the point across): [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why should a role *not* exist within a guild? If a invalid role is passed `commands.RoleNotFound` is raised, you handle that error in an error handler

Comment: [EvieePy's error_handler.py on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612) and [vcokltfre's error handler from their bot tutorial](https://vcokltfre.dev/tutorial/12-errors/) are both good places to learn about proper error handling, such as the one mentioned by Lukasz.